# New to fortran: non-numeric character errors

Tags: fortran

I get a bunch of errors "non-numeric character at...." and "unclassifiable argument". I am new to fortran and I don't know what is going on:

```
program ex
implicit none
include 'support.f90'

integer N
integer info
parameter(N=10)
real*8 D0(0:N,0:N)
integer intep(0:N)
integer j,k
integer np1


np1=N+1

do j=0,N
   do k=0,N
      D0(j,k)=(j+k)
end do
end do



call dgefa(D0,np1,np1,intep,info)

write(*,*) info
write(*,*) intep
write(*,*) D0

stop
end
```

Comment: You should show what the actual exact full error messages are. One error I can see is that you have some declaration (`integer j,k`) after an executable statement (`np1=N+1`) -- this is not allowed, typically all declarations must come first.

Comment: If your source code is free form but you try to compile as Fortran 77 fixed form, you may see such errors.  This would happen in many compilers if you named the file with .f, for example.

Comment: need to see whats in `support.f90` as well.   `D0` strikes me as a truly horrific choice of variable name by the way.. it will be confused both with `do` and double precision exponents.

Comment: support.f90 contains the function dgefa for LU decomposition, extracted from the corresponding library. Has anyone ever used it?

Comment: if its code for a function you do not have it included in the right place. It should be either before `program` or after `end`.   (I suspect @tim18 has identified the source of the current error, but next you will see issues with statements being out of order )

Comment: `real*8` is not valid Fortran and was never part of any ISO FORTRAN/Fortran standard.